# Suddenly getting No Current Record error on database that has been working for years

Tags: ms-access-2016

I have a custom database application using Access 2016 (MS365 account) with backend data on a file server and a local front end with many VBA-driven forms.  All has been working sweetly for several years, until this morning when myself and the all other users started to receive "No Current Record" errors on certain forms (not all).
I assumed it was a rogue record or corrupt DB so I went back to the previous day's backup data but  the same problem occurred. No front-end code changes have been done recently, and in any case different users are using slightly different versions of the FE system, yet all suffer the problem, so it's not specific to particular VBA.

I went back many weeks of full data backups - all throw the same error now, although had worked fine at the time of course.

I've repaired and compacted, uncompiled and so on, but it won't clear the error.

I have a strange hunch it might relate to an Office update, as I believe the problem was not present on a machine that happened to be disconnected from the internet, but this is only 80% certain.

Has anyone ever had problems arising after updates?  I cannot think of anything that has changed in the data or the front end so I'm struggling to understand what else it can be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There have been multiple reports now that this may be a bug caused by Patch Tuesday updates.  Refer to https://www.devhut.net/latest-office-update-version-2204-source-of-new-bugs/

Comment: Thanks for highlighting that - I had been searching yesterday for similar reports but so far had not found them.  Now I see several.  At least I'm not alone and not going crazy. 
I will monitor the situation with MS and hopefully this gets fixed.  I note that although clearing the repeated messages is a pain, it is not completely stopping users work with the data, so we are able to continue.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).